# How to collect sub arrays are new Arrays using `computed` method?

Tags: arrays, ember.js

I have a list of arrays which contains sub `arrays`. how to collect those arrays and return them as new array?

here is my attempt but it does not work:

```
transactions: Ember.computed.map('model.cardList', function(card, index ){
        return card.get('transactions');
    },[]), // collecting all sub arrays but not works!!

sortedCards: Ember.computed(function(){
        return this.get('model.cardList'); //length 4 
    }.property([])), //can i store here?
```

What is the correct way to collect the sub arrays from parent arrays? It is required for sorting purpose.

Thanks in advance.

Trying here, but nothing works:
[Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/075901a61af5646acccaf9f6d4774672?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C)

*Update*

According to the twiddle, I would like to print the `categoryName` with fruit name(s) as a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your solution at the end demands working with arrays of arrays and keeping them sorted, look at the following solution.
I have added a new field called `origin` to your model so that we have another field to sort by:

```
  model(){
    return {
      "values" : [
      {
        "category" : "categoryD",
        "origin": "Kongo",
        "fruits" :[{"name":"banana"},{"name":"gova"}]
      },
      {
        "category" : "categoryA",
        "origin": "Italy",
        "fruits" :[{"name":"apple"},{"name":"orange"}]
      },
      {
        "category" : "categoryC",
        "origin": "Marocco",
        "fruits" :[{"name":"pineapple"}]
      },
      {
        "category" : "categoryB",
        "origin": "Brasil",
        "fruits" :[{"name":"mongo"}]
      }
    ]
  }
```

}

And this is how your controller may look if you want to keep the sorting field dynamic:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

  shouldSortByCategory: true,

  values: Ember.computed.reads('model.values'),      

  valuesSortingDynamic: Ember.computed('shouldSortByCategory', function(){
     return (Ember.get(this, 'shouldSortByCategory') ? ['category:asc'] : ['origin:asc'])
  }),

  valuesSortedDynamically: Ember.computed.sort('values', 'valuesSortingDynamic'),

  actions: {
    changeSortField(){
       this.toggleProperty('shouldSortByCategory'); 
    },
  },

});
```

I do not care about sorting direction now (`asc` vs `desc`), but the field by which we sort is dynamic: `category` vs `origin` and is distinguished by the `shouldSortByCategory` flag.

The template looks pretty much the same:

```
<ul>
{{#each valuesSortedDynamically as |value|}}
 <li>

 {{#if shouldSortByCategory}}
   <strong>{{value.category}}</strong> - {{value.origin}}
 {{else}}
   <strong>{{value.origin}}</strong> - {{value.category}}
 {{/if}}

   <ul>
   {{#each value.fruits as |fruit|}}
     <li>{{fruit.name}}</li>
   {{/each}}
   </ul>
 </li>
{{/each}}

</ul>
```

Adjusted twiddle is to be found here: [twiddle with dynamic sorting](https://ember-twiddle.com/3e20af76acea5e9547e313dfbfd30b9e?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C).

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

Cumulating all fruits into a single array preserving info about the category they belong to can be achieved as follows:

```
  arrayOfFruitsArray: Ember.computed('model.values.[]', function(){
    const values = this.get('model.values');
    const cumulatedfruits = Ember.A();

    values.forEach((value)=>{
      const category = Ember.get(value, 'category');
      const fruits = Ember.get(value, 'fruits');

      fruits.forEach((fruit)=>{
        fruit.category = category;
        cumulatedfruits.pushObject(fruit);
      })
    });

    return cumulatedfruits;
  })
```

Updated [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/3e20af76acea5e9547e313dfbfd30b9e?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C).

Comment: Pavol,Actually i reque the result should be, All sub arrays are require to collect as separate array( our case fruits.). See my requirement here : https://jsfiddle.net/n098e0sy/1/  and the fruits are sortable.thanks for answering.

Comment: I do not see in twiddle can you please update the `twiddle` too..?

Comment: @3gwebtrain added link to twiddle

Comment: I agree. will it impact to models? because I require to update the model. Any how many more thanks to you!!! By the way what is this? `'model.values.[]'` removing this as well works fine. is this requrie?

Comment: AFAIK this line: `fruit.category = category;` will update your fruits in the memory. If this behavior is not intended, you can create a new object `const o = Ember.Object.create(fruit);` and set its category `Ember.set(o, 'category', category);`

Answer (score 0):

In your case you don't even have to compute sub-arrays of array.
Given the model that you load as follows (taken from your twiddle):

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model(){
        return {
            "values" : [
              {
                "category" : "category1",
                "fruits" :[{"name":"banana"},{"name":"gova"}]
              },
              {
                "category" : "category2",
                "fruits" :[{"name":"apple"},{"name":"orange"}]
              },
              {
                "category" : "category3",
                "fruits" :[{"name":"pineapple"}]
              },
              {
              "category" : "category4",
              "fruits" :[{"name":"mongo"}]
              }
            ]
        }
  }
});
```

It's enough that you iterate over your arrays in the template:

```
<ul>
{{#each model.values as |value|}}
 <li>
 {{value.category}}
   <ul>
   {{#each value.fruits as |fruit|}}
     <li>{{fruit.name}}</li>
   {{/each}}
   </ul>
 </li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

Here is the respective [Gist](https://gist.github.com/xamoom-pali/3e20af76acea5e9547e313dfbfd30b9e). Note that the only file I touched is the [template](https://gist.github.com/xamoom-pali/3e20af76acea5e9547e313dfbfd30b9e#file-templates-application-hbs).

Comment: yes, I tried that. but the matter is I require to sort the datas from extranal functions

Comment: By what do you need to sort? By category? Or do you need to show the fruits sorted within a category?

Comment: The filter button nested in header. when user clicks on filter by date, or filter by name or filter by price my models has to refreshed and updated

Comment: I am trying to filter and send the datas from controller. please correct me wherever I am wrong